# Trigger CSS animation when a div scrolls into view using Skrollr.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, skrollr

I would like to trigger an animation just as an element scrolls into view. If possible, I would like to do the same using Skrollr.js. This is my current code:

```
<div class="bounceIn" data-bottom-top="animation: anim 1.5s 1;">
      ...
</div>
```

(The animation name is anim, it runs for 1.5 seconds, once)

The code does trigger the animation for the element but it does so at document load as skrollr.init() is at $(document).ready()
If anyone could correct my code, that would be highly appreciated.

Edit -- here is the js fiddle, i want the anim div to sort of scale up reveal

```
https://jsfiddle.net/sankalpg6/hekh2r42/
```

Comment: Can you make a js.fiddle?

Comment: Why are you using transform scale in your keyframes to make it bounce? There are plenty of other ways that you can achieve that same animation that would be easier to implement.

Comment: could you please elaborate? i would be highly obliged

Comment: I'll look into making a solution that I hope is close to what you are looking for later. If it isn't, I'm not sure I'll be able to help.

Comment: I just noticed in my trial, whenever I resized the window, the animation was triggered, now I'm just confused

Comment: I am really busy at work and haven't had a chance to look into this further. Hopefully someone else can help. Or if I get to it before you do, I'll see what I can do. I'm fairly confident I know what to do though.

Comment: thanks, i hope you can help, i haven't yet got it.